# Wget игнорирование страниц но при этом скачивался файлы

Tags: linux, wget

Вот мой код:

```
wget https://download-a.akamaihd.net/files/media_publication/6d/osg_U_0{1..3}.mp3
```

Проблема заключается в том, что там, где файлы от osg_U_001 и до osg_U_003 они все располагаются в разных каталогов

(например https://download-a.akamaihd.net/files/media_publication/6d/,

https://download-a.akamaihd.net/files/media_publication/13/,

[https://download-a.akamaihd.net/files/media_publication/9с/](https://download-a.akamaihd.net/files/media_publication/9%D1%81/) и т. д.). И я хочу чтобы wget пропустил эти символы (6d, 13, 9c ...) и все равно устанавливал эти файлы. Это возможно так сделать?

Есть вопросы? Задавайте мне. Буду очень благодарен за ваш любой ответ!

Comment: Нет не возможно. Если у вас нет списка каталогов

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.